# PHP - why use a class static variable?

Tags: php, variables, static

I'm sorry if this is a very basic and long question but I am a newbie.

In trying to work out the difference in PHP between a regular class variable and a class variable that is static I used the following logic:

To use a normal class variable you create an object and use the object's variable but when using a class's static variable you do not create an object but refer directly to the static variable. This is as documented but I wondered why have a class with a static variable? I reasoned that because you don't create an object, any instance that refers to the same class's static variable will see the same value. i.e. if one instance sets the class's static variable to equal 2 other instances that read the class's static variable will get the value as 2. I believe this is how it works in some other languages e.g. C# and from my logic it makes sense.

When I tried testing my theory I found it not to be true. Using the code below each instance has it's own value for the class's static variable i.e. if I go to the page and then refresh it I get the same result each time for the class's regular and static variables. I was expecting the static variable to start at 2 the first time I refresh the page.

My questions are is my code bugged and if not why use static variables in a class? I do see the benefit of using static variables in a method.

```
<?php

require_once "./TRYclassVari.php";
require_once "./TRYstaticVari.php";

$classVari = new ClassVari;
$fredClassBefore = $classVari->classVariable;
$classVari->classVariable++;
$fredClassAfter = $classVari->classVariable;
$classVari->classVariable++;
$fredClassAfterAnother = $classVari->classVariable;

//$staticVari = new staticVari;
$fredStaticBefore = StaticVari::$statVari;
StaticVari::$statVari++;
$fredStaticAfter = StaticVari::$statVari;
StaticVari::$statVari++;
$fredStaticAfterAnother = StaticVari::$statVari;

echo "Class vari before = {$fredClassBefore}<br>";
echo "Class vari after = {$fredClassAfter}<br>";
echo "Class vari after another = {$fredClassAfterAnother}<br>";
echo "Stat Vari before = {$fredStaticBefore}<br>";
echo "Stat vari after = {$fredStaticAfter}<br>";
echo "Stat vari after another = {$fredStaticAfterAnother}<br>";
```

The output from the code is same after I first call the page and after a refresh:

Class vari before =

Class vari after = 1

Class vari after another = 2

Stat Vari before =

Stat vari after = 1

Stat vari after another = 2

Comment: Hm, what exactly did _you_ expect as a result? I cannot imagine another outcome

Comment: A static variable would not persist between requests unless you're storing and retrieving it from somewhere.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's what the OP meant. Yes, each script invocation is done in a completely fresh environment, as it had been the first. You have to look into session-handling and object serialization to persist information between calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation seems correct, but you have confused two instances of an object with two *requests* of the script.

Or to put it simple:

### A static variable is like a global variable.

But as others have already mentioned: Nothing persists between requests (when you refresh) unless you explicitly store it somewhere like the session, a file or a database.